# How much would self mending clothes cost?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items

My friend is running a pathfinder game and I was wondering how much it would cost for my character to have clothes that mend themselves should anything happen to them (getting stabbed/ripped, catching fire, ect.). He said I could have them but we couldn't figure out how much they'd cost.

Comment: Are they just self mending? or are they also self-cleaning?
How quickly do they self-mend?
If in a pinch I had no torch, could I take my self-mending shirt, wrap it around the stick and use as a Everburning torch -- since it would repair faster than it it burnt away?

Answer (score 26):

You want to buy a [Sleeves of Many Garments](http://www.pathfindersrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/r-z/sleeves-of-many-garments) for 200gp.  This item, when you put it on, lets you transform your current garments into any other nonmagical clothing, which will always be clean and mended unless you specify otherwise.  If your new clothing gets damaged, you can fix it by removing and re-equipping the sleeves.

---

Let me also talk about how you'd go about pricing a custom magic item to produce this effect.

You want to look at http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/magicItems/magicItemCreation.html which describes how the DM can assign prices to custom-made magic items.  Be warned that this generic framework does have some loopholes, so it's important to sanity-check the final result of any calculation.  Your DM has the right to adjust prices up or down, or simply to veto any item created with those rules.

You're creating an item based on the spell [mending](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/spells/mending.html).  This is a cantrip, which counts as a spell level of 1/2 for purposes of magic item creation.  If you use a caster level of 1 (the minimum), it can mend objects weighing up to 1lb.  The cost for a "continuous mending effect" would be (2000gp) * (spell level 1/2) * (caster level 1) = 1000gp.

You might argue that there should be a discount because this magic effect doesn't let you mend just anything, it's limited to only affect your clothes.  Or you might have to pay more, because the mending spell technically only affects objects weighing up to 1lb per caster level, and your pants and boots probably weigh more than that.

(In fact, we know that a very similar item costs 200gp, so in this case there should be a steep discount!)

This effect would still be pretty slow: the mending spell repairs 1d4 points of damage every 10 minutes.

Note that, for the same 1000gp price (and again with DM approval), you could get a *ring of mending* which would allow you to repair anything.  (Again limited to items weighing 1lb.)  You would probably have to concentrate on the repair process when using the ring, whereas the built-into-your-clothes version would operate on its own.

If you're looking for fun silly spell effects, consider getting a *ring of [prestidigitation](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/spells/prestidigitation.html#prestidigitation)* for the same 1000gp, which lets you "slowly lift 1 pound of material", "color, clean, or soil items in a 1-foot cube each round", "chill, warm, or flavor 1 pound of nonliving material", or "create small objects, but they look crude and artificial".  Which is better: the power to magically repair your clothes, or the power to magically clean them?

If you're a spellcasting class, you can probably take the *mending* or *prestidigition* spells as cantrips, which lets you use the effect at-will without paying money for a magic item.

Finally, consider the [hat of disguise](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/h-l/hat-of-disguise) for 1800gp, which lets you change your appearance by illusion.  This lets you *look* like your clothes are cleaned and mended, and it also lets you look like someone completely different, at will.

Comment: I'd say self-mending clothes are less useful than a *Hand of the Mage*, so I'd rule that the former's price should be less than the latter's 900 gp. That's just me, though.

Comment: @GMJoe I agree with you that a self-mending clothes isn't very useful, but I didn't feel like it was within the scope of the question to arbitrarily cut the price in half.  ^_^;  I thought it would be more useful for Nicholas and his DM if I just listed the unmodified price for several items which produced roughly the effect he was looking for.

Comment: Fair enough - I mentioned it because the guideline given in the rules is to compare the pricing of new items to other existing items, but guidelines have a tendency to be fuzzy anyway.

Comment: Another item that came to mind is the _[Sleeves of Many Garments](http://www.pathfindersrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/r-z/sleeves-of-many-garments)_ for 200gp. A quick way to make yourself look cleaned up and presentable just before visiting the local noble.

Comment: @AgentAquarius wow, yeah -- that's better than anything I listed.  You should make that a top-level answer.  :)

Comment: Thank you all for the answers. The reasoning for the question was because my character isn't human but is posing as a human and he asked what I would do if my clothes got ripped and they saw I was lying and I asked if i could have self mending clothes to help me hide. He said I could but we couldn't really figure out a price. I wasn't going to use it for anything cheesy with it and my secret is gonna come out eventually. Just not after the first fight.

Answer (score 16):

Dan B's answer is probably the best rules based answer you're going to get, but I would like to take a different tack. Rather than start by looking at what the rules say, you should start with how useful this item will actually be to your campaign.

In most campaigns, things like hygiene and the state of your clothes don't really come up, both because they're easy enough to deal with if you actually care and because there are more interesting things you can do with your time. In such a campaign, self-mending clothes provide literally no benefit. This is a bit problematic, since the rules for determining item cost assume that the item will actually help you in some small way. In this type of campaign I'd do one of two things:

1. Give the upgrade away for free. It has no mechanical benefit, so I don't have to worry about them unbalancing things, but they are an interesting roleplaying addition and that is worth rewarding. I might also consider giving the other players similar, mechanically useless, but flavorful items. Some RPGs, like Numenera, actually do something similar as part of character creation, with each character getting a random item that could either add flavor or serve as a plot hook, but has no real mechanical significance.
2. Most, mundane, clothing goes for between 1 and 10gp. The three exceptions, in the SRD, are doctor's clothing, noble's clothing, and royal clothing, which go for a whopping 150gp, 75gp, and 200gp respectively. The doctors's clothing actually gives you a +2 vs contact diseases, so I won't be discussing them, but that might help put things in perspective. For the remaining two pieces, the SRD claims the price increase is because precious metals and gems are worked into the clothing, but in a world as magical as D&D it would be reasonable to assume that the aristocracy would want basic convenience enchantments on their clothing. In such a case, you could rule that Noble's get a self-repair function with their clothing, while royals get self-repair and self-cleaning. You'd then just charge the same price for different cuts with the same enchantment.

Conversely, if you're playing in the type of game where this sort of thing will matter **and** your clothes will repair fast enough for it to be relevant, you could either follow the enchanted item guidelines or treat it like armor, with the different types of armor telling you how fast it will regenerate (and giving you an idea of how much it will benefit you).

Finally, all of this assumes you're talking about generic clothing. If the clothing is inherently useful (like, say, a vacuum suit) then an auto-repair function becomes much more valuable and should cost an appropriate amount. Possibly the equivalent of a +1 enchantment, if it's important enough.